# Does Graphics.DrawImage check if the image is within the clip bounds?

Tags: c#

EG:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(400,400));
g.DrawImage(something, new Point(-400,-400))
```

Would it still run the drawing code to draw the image or does it check if the Point passed to it will put the image in bounds of the clipboard (ClipBounds)?

Furthermore, if there was say 25 images being drawn, would checking if the image is in bounds or not yield a performance increase?

Comment: You can now look for yourself on the new and Roslyn-powered [Microsoft ReferenceSource site](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs#45d0f8c901e94452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)?

> Encapsulates a GDI+ drawing surface.

What is surface? It's 2d rectangle.

What is rectangle? It's array of points, limited by bounds.

Can you physically draw a point outside array? No.

So only points inside bounds will be drawn? Yep.

And points outside will be ignored? Yep.

Automatically? Auto-magically.

And bitmaps? And bitmaps.

*Try to draw bitmaps inside and outside, measure time and see for yourself!*

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out would be to try it, IMO. Note that the C# code referenced merely calls a native method, and I saw no indication of what that method does with the clipping area/image bounds. In looking at the source for ReactOS, there are sizable number of operations done (such as copying the source image data to a temporary buffer) whether or not any data is copied to the actual target bitmap. This is no indication that Microsoft did the same, which is why you should test and find out.